# How to use UITableView.ScrollPosition in tableView in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to increase the font size of the text if it's in the middle of the screen while scrolling in a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method and then change the text size if the `contentOffset.y` of the tableView is equal or greater than half of your screen height.